# Firebird 1.5.3: How to add FK with connected users to the DB?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, firebird

I use FB1.5.3 and need to eventually add some FK to the database.
It happens that if I try to do it while anyone else is connected to the DB I get an exception.

Is there a way to add an FK while the system is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way.

It's a known limitation that has been removed in Firebird 2.0. You should either upgrade, or live with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a limitation on firebird 1.5 and earlier.
Try google for (firebird foreign key "object is in use").
hth